# Pass dynamically generated div id's from Rails to javascript/coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, html, coffeescript

I have a list of items for which I would like to reveal a more detailed description per item under the name of the item at the click of a button or link. For example, a very simple implementation would be using .toggle(). In Rails I have this for the descriptions:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= div_for(product, :class => "descriptions") do %>
        <%= product.description %>
    <% end %>
    <input type="button" id="button_<%= product.id %>" value="Show/hide" />
<% end %>
```

I would have to catch the dynamically generated div id's at the javascript/coffeescript side:

```
jQuery ->
$('#button_?????').click ->
    $('#product_ ????').toggle()
```

However, I'm unable to get this to work.

On the other hand, I might be able to accomplish the same result using something like '.closets()', like this:

```
jQuery ->
$('#button').click ->
    $('#button').closest('.descriptions').toggle()
```

However, I can't get this to work either. It seems to be a fairly simple task, but I'm just too unexperienced in javascript to get this to work. How to catch these dynamically generated divs on the javascript side? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture the dynamically generated `div`'s from Rails, you would normally do the following:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.descriptions');
```

Keep in mind, though, that `querySelectorAll` is NOT live, therefore any changes to the DOM will not be reflected in the `NodeList`.

jQuery has a great solution for this, as @MrDanA had suggested. However, the `click` handler needs to be on the button and not the description. Also, `live` has been deprecated. It needs to be replaced with `on`.

```
$('.descriptions').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var button = $this.next(); // assuming that the button is the next sibling
  button.on('click', function(e) {
    $this.toggle();
    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent page from jumping to the top of the page
  });
});
```

This should give you a good baseline. Let me know exactly how you'd like it to behave.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I really expected this to work, but it doesn't, somehow. The html looks like this:

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I really expected this to work, but it doesn't, somehow. The html is a list of divs with class "products" that each contain a div of class "product-names", a div of class "descriptions" and the button. The idea would be that the "descriptions" div of each product separately could be shown or hidden with the button. Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Nick, this works perfectly if put inline, so it must be something else (not) going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If only DIVs you care about in this case will have a class of "descriptions", you can use [jQuery's live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It would look like this:

```
$('.descriptions').live("click", function() { ... });
```

So whenever a new item with the descriptions class is formed, it will gain that jQuery code for its click event.